# Trying to assign an str.find return to a variable

Tags: python

I want to assign a str.find() return to a variable besides str.find, but i'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: `var = str.find("substring")`

Comment: and the substring is where i set the name i want?

Comment: Yes, the argument to `str.find()` is the substring that you're searching for within `str`. `foo = "abc123".find("123")` sets `foo` to `3`.

Comment: You assign the result of `str.find()` to a variable the same way you assign the result of any other function to a variable.

Comment: wait my bad i meant how do i save the output of str.find() into a variable, ex. str.find(".") decimal = "returned str.find() output"

Comment: You just do an ordinary variable assignment, just like any other function. You use `=` to assign it.

Comment: can you give me an example because im not picturing this

Comment: I posted an answer, what more do you need?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find)...

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Assignment is one of the first things any course, book, or tutorial will teach.

Answer (score 1):

You use `=` to assign it.

```
mystr = '123.456'
dotpos =  mystr.find('.')
```

Now the variable `dotpos` will contain `3`.

Comment: Usual comment: Please don't shadow builtins with variable names in examples. Can we use `astr`, `s`, something that isn't going to shadow the `str` constructor? I know you know not to do it in real code, but the people who ask questions like this usually don't. __Update__: Awesome, you fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @ZachMcGivern: If you assign to the same variable again, it will replace it. Of course, you could just assign to a different name. If you don't understand how variables work in Python, you _really_ need to stop trying to write code, and run through the Python tutorial to figure out the basics (if not take proper classes).